# SQL: Values in column listed twice after pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

When querying a specific table, I need to change the structure of the result, making it so that all values from a given year are on the same row, in separate columns that identify the category that the value belongs to.

The table looks like this (example data):

```
year | category | amount
1991 | A of s   | 56
1992 | A of s   | 55
1993 | A of s   | 40
1994 | A of s   | 51
1995 | A of s   | 45
1991 | Total    | 89
1992 | Total    | 80
1993 | Total    | 80
1994 | Total    | 81
1995 | Total    | 82
```

The result I need is this:

```
year | a_of_s | total
1991 | 56     | 89
1992 | 55     | 80
1993 | 40     | 80
1994 | 51     | 81
1995 | 45     | 82
```

From what I can understand I need to use **pivot**. However, my problem seems to be that I don't understand pivot. I've attempted to adapt the queries of solutions in similar questions where pivot seems to be part of the answer, and so far what I've come up with is this:

```
SELECT year, [A of s], [Total] FROM table
pivot (
    max(amount)
    FOR category in ([A of s], [Total])
) pvt
ORDER BY year
```

<strike>This returns the correct table structure, but all cells in the columns a_of_s and total are NULL, and every year is listed twice. What am I missing to get the result I need?</strike>

EDIT: After fixing the errors pointed out in the comments, the only real issue that remains is that years in the year column are listed twice.

Possibly related: Is the aggregate function I use in pivot (max, sum, min, etc) arbitrary?

Comment: Don't use single quotes for column references.  I vote to close such questions as typographical errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the input. I've changed to double quotes, but that might not fix the problem that you're seeing? The result I'm achieving is the same, anyway. EDIT: If I should remove the quotes entirely, how can I identify the "A of s" (containing whitespace) value in the category column?

Comment: . . Just use square braces.

Comment: Sorry, I was certain I had tried simply going without quotes, but you're right, that works just fine, even if the year column still produces each year twice. I'll wait an hour or so for any further input, then delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you really don't need to pivot your table and with the result you require you can create an alternative approach to achieve it.

This is the query i made that returns according to your requirement.

```
;With cte as
(
  select year, Amount from tbl
  where category = 'A of s'
)

select 
tbl1.year, tbl2.Amount as A_of_S, tbl1.Amount as Total
from tbl as tbl1
inner join  cte as tbl2 on tbl1.year = tbl2.year
where tbl1.category = 'Total'
```

and this is the SQL fiddle i created for you with your test day. -> [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/435b9/17)

Comment: Why query the table twice? There is no need.

Comment: @Larnu Query to get the specific data as another table to get the required  result in total.  I pity you for down voting my answer out of jealousy. My answer will work in his scenario whether how long his data is. Plus my query is working and giving the required result.

Comment: The down vote is for because there is no need to query the table twice. part of providing an answer, especially in SQL, is making sure that answer is efficient. If the OP's table is especially large the query could quite literally take twice the time.

Comment: A slow query is not a useful query. I'm sorry that you feel upset by my input and the downvote; I was only advising you how you can improve your own SQL. There is, however, no need to inflammatory comments.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler answer:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1991,'A of s',56),
                 (1992,'A of s',55),
                 (1993,'A of s',40),
                 (1994,'A of s',51),
                 (1995,'A of s',45),
                 (1991,'Total',89),
                 (1992,'Total',80),
                 (1993,'Total',80),
                 (1994,'Total',81),
                 (1995,'Total',82)) V([year],category, amount))
SELECT [year],
       MAX(CASE category WHEN 'A of s' THEN amount END) AS [A of s],
       MAX(CASE category WHEN 'Total' THEN amount END) AS Total
FROM VTE
GROUP BY [year];
```

Comment: @ARr0w I know your downvote is in response to my own on yours, but have you therefore tried running my SQL? Also, the VTE is because the OP has supplied no DDL and Sample data. I don't have access to their table, so how would i query against their table? This is a query that **anyone** can run without having access to the OP's SQL Server. The result is what the OP specified for. The method is different, to start, There is no `GROUP BY` in your query, secondly, you parse the table twice, which I'm already informed you. You also use a `DISTINCT`, which is often quite expensive.